# How can I get Perl to detect bad UTF-8 sequences?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I'm running Perl 5.10.0 and Postgres 8.4.3, and strings into a database, which is behind a [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class).

These strings should be in UTF-8, and therefore my database is running in UTF-8. Unfortunatly some of these strings are bad, containing malformed UTF-8, so when I run it I'm getting an exception

`DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb5`

I thought that I could simply ignore the invalid ones, and worry about the malformed UTF-8 later, so using this code, it should flag and ignore the bad titles.

```
if(not utf8::valid($title)){
   $title="Invalid UTF-8";
}
$data->title($title);
$data->update();
```

However Perl seems to think that the strings are valid, but it still throws the exceptions.

How can I get Perl to detect the bad UTF-8?

Comment: This is off topic, but is there any particular reason why you are using 5.10.0 and not 5.10.1? There are some good compat fixes in 5.10.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, please follow the documentation - the `utf8` module should **only** be used in the 'use utf8;' form to indicate that your source code is UTF-8 instead of Latin-1. Don't use any of the utf8 functions.

Perl makes the distinction between bytes and UTF-8 strings. In byte mode, Perl doesn't know or care what encoding you are using, and will use Latin-1 if you print it. Take for example the Euro sign (€). In UTF-8 this is 3 bytes, 0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC. If you print the length of these bytes, Perl will return 3. Again, it doesn't care about the encoding. It can be any bytes or any encoding, legal or illegal.

If you use the `Encode` module and call `Encode::decode("UTF-8', $bytes)` you will get a new string which has the so-called UTF8 flag set. Perl now knows your string is in UTF-8, and will return a length of 1.

The problem that `utf8::valid` only applies to the second type of string. Your strings are probably in the first form, byte mode, and `utf8::valid` just returns true for anything in byte form. This is documented in the perldoc.

The solution is to get Perl to decode your byte strings as UTF-8, and detect any errors. This can be done with FB_CROAK as brian d foy explains:

```
my $ustring =
    eval { decode( 'UTF-8', $byte_string, FB_CROAK ) }
    or die "Could not decode string: $@";
```

You can then catch that error and skip those invalid strings.

Or if you know your code is mostly UTF-8 with a few invalid sequences here and there, you can use:

```
my $ustring = decode( 'UTF-8', $byte_string );
```

which uses the default mode of `FB_DEFAULT`, replacing invalid characters with U+FFFD, the Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (diamond with question mark in it).

You can then pass the string directly to your database driver in most cases. Some drivers may require you to re-encode the string back to byte form first:

```
my $byte_string = encode('UTF-8', $ustring);
```

There are also regexes online that you can use to check for valid UTF-8 sequences before calling `decode` (check other Stack Overflow answers). If you use those regexes, you don't need to do any encoding or decoding.

Finally, please use `UTF-8` rather than `utf8` in your calls to `decode`. The latter is more lax and allows some invalid UTF-8 sequences (such as sequences outside the Unicode range) to be allowed through.

Comment: Encode::encode is the wrong approach here, encode is for getting bytes in a specified charset out of UTF-8-Perlstrings, but if is_utf8 fails one doesn't have such a string and encode would produce garbage. What one really want to do is use Encode::decode to first get a UTF-8-Perlstring out of whatever charset used for $string. If one doesn't know which charset this is, one needs to guess or fail or whatever, but surely not encode to anything else, because this makes life only worse. FB_CROAK is your friend! :-)

Comment: `is_utf8()` doesn't detect valid UTF8 at all--it just detects whether perl's internal UTF8 flag is on or not. It's easy to turn that flag on with invalid data.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning thanks for the comment, I have updated the answer and hopefully it reflects reality now :)

Comment: Re "*Don't use any of the utf8 functions.*", There's no reason not to use `utf8::encode`, `utf8::decode`, `utf8::upgrade` and `utf8::downgrade`. (OTOH, don't use `Encode::_utf8_on`, `Encode::_utf8_off`, `Encode::is_utf8`, `utf8::is_utf8`, and `utf8::valid`)

Comment: Encoding and decoding in place is quite advanced I think. Better to use `Encode`.

Comment: I got `Bareword "FB_CROAK" not allowed while "strict subs" in use ...`. Fixed by replacing `FB_CROAK` with `Encode::FB_CROAK`.

Answer (score 9):

How are you getting your strings? Are you sure that Perl thinks that they are UTF-8 already? If they aren't decoded yet (that is, octets interpreted as some encoding), you need to do that yourself:

```
    use Encode;

    my $ustring =
      eval { decode( 'utf8', $byte_string, FB_CROAK ) }
      or die "Could not decode string: $@";
```

Better yet, if you know that your source of strings is already UTF-8, you need to read that source as UTF-8. Look at the code you have that gets the strings to see if you are doing that properly.

Comment: Return a true value from the `eval` to avoid misidentifying the empty string.

Comment: Or I could use // instead of `or` to test for definedness.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation for `utf8::valid` points out, it returns true if the string is marked as UTF-8 and it's valid UTF-8, *or if the string isn't UTF-8 at all*. Although it's impossible to tell without seeing the code in context and knowing what the data is, most likely what you want isn't the "valid utf8" check at all; probably you just need to do

```
$data->title( Encode::encode("UTF-8", $title) )
```

Comment: Encode::encode on non UTF-8-Perlstrings will make things only worse, don't do that. Use either decode(!) or deal with the fact that you have some bytes which should be strings, but you don't know their charset anymore.